# JavaScript Combinations

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript object, and I would like to make combinations where each element is the "base" to generate the combinations.

[image]

would be something like,

`[[5, 155, 158], [5, 156, 159], [5, 157, 572], [5, 157, 572]]`

I tried this way, but I've been trying for a few days and without success. It's something very raw, to see if it would be successful, I tried to do recursive functions but I was not successful

```js
const v = function(obj, array) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach((val) => {
    let arr = val[1];
    let base = val[0]
    arr.forEach((el) => {
      let cop = [];
      Object.entries(obj).forEach((v) => {
        if (v[0] != base) {
          v[1].forEach((l) => {
            if (tes(v[1], cop) <= 0 && cop.indexOf(l) == -1) {
              cop.push(l);
            }
          });

          if (array.indexOf(cop) == -1) {
            array.push(cop)
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

let array = []
v(_combis, array)
console.log(array)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please [edit] and make it a [mcve] with example input and expected output

Comment: Why does `[5, 157, 572]` appear twice?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the exact problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right you want to something like this

```js
const obj = {
    3: [5],
    57: [155, 156, 157],
    58: [158, 159, 572, 573]
}

function generate(obj) {

    function findMax() {
        const lengths = [...Object.values(obj).map(item => item.length)];
        return Math.max(...lengths);
    }

    const max = findMax();

    const globalArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        const tempArr = []; 
        for (let j = 0; j < Object.keys(obj).length; j++) {
            const element = obj[Object.keys(obj)[j]];
            
            if (i < element.length) {
                tempArr.push(element[i])
            } else {
                tempArr.push(element[element.length - 1])
            }
        }
        globalArr.push(tempArr);
    }
   
    return globalArr;
    
}

console.log(generate(obj));
```

Comment: yes, but do this with all values

@Sandex

Comment: I can generate in the amount you sent, but with everyone it ends up going very wrong